# When did desktop Safari add support for <meta name="referrer" content="origin">?

Tags: safari, http-referer

Safari 7 on my laptop supports the following tag:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

Answers to a previous question document support for various other browsers: "[Why isn't the Referral Removed for Google HTTPS -> HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922143/why-isnt-the-referral-removed-for-google-https-http/29505577#29505577)"?

Did Safari 6 support this?  Based another article from the web, it looks like Safari 5 did not.

Safari 5:
http://smerity.com/articles/2013/where_did_all_the_http_referrers_go.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: at the latest, IOS/Safari 7.  Unclear if this was in Safari 6 or not.
http://searchengineland.com/rejoice-safari-is-once-again-providing-google-referral-information-in-ios-168493

FWIW, if anyone else is looking here, it's now in Firefox 38+:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=704320

Per direct contacts, it's included in IE11 and Chrome 25+ (including mobile, earlier on desktop).